# How to skip line while reading a file in java

Tags: java, input

How would I skip the line while reading a file in java? every time I run it, it crashes when it goes to the empty line.

The file contains:

```
Sue     12.60  8 4 5 8 2

Juan    13.75  4 2 7 5 10

Betty   12.10  9 3 5 7.  
Jin     14.9   8 8 2 3 4 1
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DATA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = null;

        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("EmployeeData.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            String name = lineScan.next();
            double rate = lineScan.nextDouble();
            int sum = 0;
            while (lineScan.hasNextInt()) {
                sum = sum + lineScan.nextInt();
            }

            double salary = rate * sum;
            if (salary > 400) {
                double tax = salary - (salary * 0.33);
                System.out.print(name + " worked for a total of: " + sum + " hours at $" + rate);
                System.out.printf(" hours at $ %.2f%n", rate);
                System.out.printf(" an hour for a gross pay of $ %.2f%n", salary);
                System.out.println("\nAfter 33% taxes their total net pay should be " + tax);
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                double tax = salary - (salary * 0.25);
                System.out.print(name + " worked for a total of: " + sum);
                System.out.printf(" hours at $ %.2f", rate);
                System.out.printf(" an hour for a gross pay of $ %.2f", salary);
                System.out.println("\nAfter 25% taxes their total net pay should be $" + tax);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: how would i skip the line while reading a file in java? everytime I run it, it crashes when it goes to the empty line.

Answer (score 1):

To skip the empty line

```
String line = input.nextLine();

if (line.isEmpty()) continue;
```

Comment: `.isEmpty()` is nicer ?

Comment: `length() < 1` does seem weirdly vague.

Comment: Im not sure if we have learned about the .isEmpty continue, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can test if `line.length () == 0` but `isEmpty` is a very basic method on the standard `String` class

Comment: @TianDitol that are 2 very different things `isEmpty` to test the line, and `continue` to skip it and pass to the next iteration